# How to unlock the 4th world in Plants vs. Zombies 2

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

How do you unlock the 4th world in Plants vs. Zombies 2 ???
I've got all 72 stars from the previous 3 worlds,
but I can't seem to enter the 4th world.

I think I was given a chance to enter the 4th world once,
but there was a warning that having more stars would be helpful.
I think I decided to earn more stars.  But now I can't find anyway
to enter the 4th world.

There's a star portal in the 3rd world.  And when I click on that star
it just goes back to the time-space taco map (shown below).

I'm wondering if this is a bug in the game.
Or perhaps, they'll update the app in the future with access to the 4th world.

[image: Pvz time-space taco map]

Comment: Thanks @JasonBerkan .  I'll wait for them to release it.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - is there official confirmation of that?

Comment: @DVK - Google "PvZ 2 Far Future".  There are a number of news articles discussing the future release.  I couldn't find anything on PopCap's site about it, though.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - are they speculations, or based on some sort of (purported) PopCap leaks?

Comment: @DVK - Apparently based on a PopCap / EA announcement at Gamescom in August.  There is a tweet from the official account: https://twitter.com/PlantsvsZombies/status/369833664827650049

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Far Future was released on the 27th of March, 2014](https://twitter.com/PlantsvsZombies/status/449351146184769536):

> **@PlantsVsZombies**
>   The Future is... NOW! Far Future, now available in #PvZ2!

You can unlock it like the other worlds; i.e. paying $4.99 or using a World Key obtained by defeating the 8th level of any of the previously unlocked worlds.

---

To preemptively answer similar questions about future worlds... If the world in question has a giant padlock on it, then it can be unlocked. Otherwise it will be added in a future release.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

@JasonBerkan gave the answer in a comment.
The fourth world has not been released yet.
So there is currently no way to unlock it.